# what can cause the machine type to change between core files generated by different binaries?

Tags: linux, gdb

What might cause the architecture to be different between the core files generated when running the following executables? Both are compiled using `g++` on the same machine.

I suspect this may have to do with `sysenter` being used, which ultimately results in the core dump being useless for debugging. I don't know if this is
expected or if there are ways to generate a proper core dump.

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20231205 (Red Hat 13.2.1-6)
```

###### File 1

```cpp
$ cat seg.cc 
int main() {
   int *ptr = nullptr;
   *ptr = 12;
}
```

```
$ readelf -h cdump 
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              CORE (Core file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         39
  Size of section headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0
```

###### File 2

```cpp
$ cat asm_test.cc 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *ptr = "Some testing string";
    static_assert(1 == __NR_write);
    // Replacing sysenter with syscall works
    asm volatile (
        "nop\n\t"
        "mov $1, %%rax\n\t" 
        "mov $1, %%rdi\n\t"
        "mov %0, %%rsi\n\t"
        "mov $5, %%rdx\n\t"
        "sysenter"
    ::"r"(ptr):"%rax", "%rsi", "%rdi", "%rdx");
    
}
```

Corresponding core dump

```
$ readelf -h cdump_asm_test 
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              CORE (Core file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         40
  Size of section headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0
```

```
$ g++ asm_test.cc -ggdb
$ file a.out 
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=7fc92674631f81d66778e134620f24dcd4e170b6, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```